# How to Query & re-organize Data from current MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following database structure:

[image: Database Structure]

And the data stored inside  is as follows:

[image: test_summary]

[image: test_details]

However, I like to select data from this `database` in the following format:
[image: What I Want]

How can I use one single `SELECT` statement to achieve this? If using one single `SELECT` statement cannot, how to achieve this by whatever `sql` code? Can someone give me the implementation?

Comment: how many different `m1-t1,m1-t2...` are possible and using sql it can not be done exactly how you listed out however it could be achieved to some extent.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, `m1-t1, m1-t2...` is not a fixed length. For instance, it could be `m1-t1, m1-t2, m1-t3, m2-t1, m2-t2, m3-t1`. The table I want should be organized by `m`.

Comment: Your desired result is nothing but pivot data and for known set of item its easy however in your case you need dynamic sql to achieve it. Check for mysql dynamic pivot table.

Comment: `x_value` is also not limited or fixed to 0, 10 and 20?

Comment: @DangeMask, yes, to simplify the problem, let's assume they are fixed to `0, 10, 20` first.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use one single SELECT statement to achieve this?

Yes, you can. You will have to play a little with `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` statement, but it can be achieved.

**EDIT:**

Let's try multiple `JOIN` statements:

```
Select sum.name, x0.y_value, x10.y_value, x20.y_value
    from test_summary as sum
    join test_details as x0 on sum.id=x0.id and x0.x_value=0
    join test_details as x10 on sum.id=x10.id and x10.x_value=10
    join test_details as x20 on sum.id=x20.id and x20.x_value=20
```

Based on answers to [multiple joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912428/4809220) and [join with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219924/4809220)

Comment: Your question was, if it can be achieved ;-) On second look, it is not so easy as I thought. I'll think about it for a while and try to find solution.

Comment: Please try my new suggestion. I'm more familiar with MS SQL so I hope my syntax is correct.

Comment: the solution you provide only works when `x_value` instance is small. If the `x_value` ranges from 0 to 100 with step 10, `0, 10, 20, 30, 40...90, 100`. This `SELECT` statement takes forever!

Comment: I asked you if it is limited. This is the reason why. I'm afraid my experience is limited to this solution.

Comment: You can also try to create indexes over detail table to speed up searching. But I'm not sure if it will significantly help.

Comment: I tried using the `index`. I put `x_value` as the index. But the speed doesn't change. It basically never are going to finish!

Comment: Is the number of x_values constant? How fast does the values change? Is this select the only use of this data? I'm trying to understand your needs. Personaly, I don't like this kind of table structure, but maybe you have the reason to use it as it is.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. Frankly speaking, this is the better table structure I can think of right now... And the key concern for me to come up with this structure is that the number of `x_values` is not fixed all time. It could be any value basically.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I can't think of any better solution :-( Maybe somebody with more experience will help.

Answer (score 0):

The things you like called pivot table, and this is out of scope of relation data base system like mySQL. So there many special platforms for OLAP. But if you do not need any comprehensive OLAP things, but produce some pivot tables using mySQL and PHP you do not need any special sql, but nedd to program such presentation by php, may be using some commercial frameworks like [this](http://demo.koolphp.net/Examples/KoolPivotTable/Firstlook/Firstlook/index.php) or some opensource [code](https://code.google.com/p/gam-pivot/source/checkout)