# How to write query that join the 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using mysql. Database sakila.
Having two tables films and language. Film table has two foreign keys language_id and original_language_id that connects to language_id primary key in language.
So what I want is to learn how to get film, it's language and original language from such structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6rXW.png)

The query will display film in its language, without original.

```
SELECT 
    film.title, film.description, film.release_year, language.*
FROM
    film
        INNER JOIN
    language ON film.language_id = language.language_id;
```

Comment: take a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912336/mysql-join-multiple-joins-on-the-same-table - you can join the `language` table twice - just use an alias `... inner join language as original_language on ...`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to select the films having language other than original language. I think a where clause will serve the purpose.

```
SELECT 
    film.title, film.description, film.release_year, language.*
FROM
    film INNER JOIN language 
         ON film.language_id = language.language_id;
    where film.language_id <> film.original_language_id
```

Or, If you just want to display language information for both the language you can follow one of below query (using subquery):

```
SELECT  film.title, film.description, film.release_year, 
        (select name from language l where l.language_id=film.language_id) language_name,
        (select name from language l where l.language_id=film.original_language_id) original_language_name
FROM film
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
SELECT a.title, a.description, a.release_year, b.language_id, b.name, b.last_update
FROM
film a
INNER JOIN
language b ON a.language_id = b.language_id;
```